# Re-order regular expression matches

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to get the match patterns to change order? For example if you have a string with letters-digits and using `preg_match_all()`, and you want the resulting match array to have the digits before the letters. Is there a way to specify this in the regular expression itself?

So `"aaa-111"` would result in matches with

```
array(0 => '111', 1 => 'aaa');
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You should order the result yourself.

Comment: Why do you want to get this? http://php.net/array-reverse

Comment: if there's only ever two results you should use array_reverse() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: can't do it progromatically because this is a configuration. Some string needs to be used for ordering things and I need to specify what parts are used for ordering through a configuration.

Comment: I think the closest you can get are named capture groups.

Comment: are named capture groups supported in php?

Comment: @matthewdaniel: Yep! :-) http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: I thought your problem stemmed from the fact the matches are used by another method or function or what have you, and they don't have any control over *how* the matches are used other than to change their order. Otherwise, why don't you skip the names altogether and just use `$match[1]` instead of `$match[2]` and vice versa?

Comment: @NullUserException one client may have m/d/Y and another d/m/Y and yet another Y/m/d and the function cannot know that so the configuration needs to allow for it

Comment: Why didn't you say you were working with dates? [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) would be a cleaner way to do this. Just define the format each client uses and your program can handle it from there. From a maintenance perspective it would be heck lot better than fiddling with ordering stuff in a regex match array too. Future programmers will thank you. Maybe even future you will thank past you, in six months you might be trying to figure "what the heck was I doing here?"

Comment: it isn't necessarily just dates, it is however the client names the file with the dates being an easy to understand example

Comment: Well, I'd argue this isn't the best approach to the problem, but to each his own. I hope you will be the only one maintaining the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps named capture groups will help. Example:

```
preg_match('/(?<alphapart>[a-z]+)-(?<numpart>[0-9]+)/', 'aaa-111', $matches);
```

$matches:

```
array('alphapart' => 'asd', 'numpart' => '111')
```

This way you can refer to the matches by a name instead of whatever order index they were matched in.

Edit: Just for accuracy, I want to note that $matches will actually include the matches by index as well, so the actual $matches will be: `array(5) { [0]=> string(7) "aaa-111" ["alphapart"]=> string(3) "aaa" [1]=> string(3) "aaa" ["numpart"]=> string(3) "111" [2]=> string(3) "111" }`

Comment: Ha! I beat you by 16 seconds :)

Comment: Didn't know that existed. +1

Comment: i could specify names that have alpha characters, strip out the numeric keys, ksort and implode, nice. Thanks everyone

Comment: @matthewdaniel That sounds like a lot of work for something that could be made very simple; eg: `preg_match('/regex/, $str, $matches); $real_order = array($matches[2], $matches[1]);`

Answer (score 3):

The order of groups in a regex is dependent on their positions in the regex and the string.  Changing the order would make it very confusing.

What you can do is use ["named groups"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

```
/(?P<letters>\w*)-(?P<digits>\d*)/
```

The array will still be in the same order, but, you can use `$matches['digits']` to easily get just the digits.

DEMO: http://ideone.com/3tRJLZ

Comment: Why a downvote?  Someone else posted the same answer, and *they* didn't get a downvote?

Comment: Could you also name the groups '0' and '1'? And would that actually reverse them in the array?

Comment: @WillemMulder No, you'll get a regex compilation error "Numeric named subpatterns are not allowed". Yeah, it was the first thing I tried.

Comment: You left out the angle brackets: `(?P<name>...)`.  It's correct in your demo code, though.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Whoops X_X  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can use lookaheads that don't push the 'cursor' and so you could first match the last part, and then the first part. It works with (?=regex)

This works:

```
(?=\w+\-(\d+))(\w+)\-\d+
```

but will also give the full match at index 0. Like ["aaa-111", "111", "aaa"]
is that a problem?

Comment: I'm not being negative, I'm stating that lookaround won't get the job done. Feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: I like to do things that others say are impossible, so I'll try :)

Comment: I didn't put in a code block, so it messed up the escape character

Comment: Your regex was wrong, it wasn't a code or escape issue. And this one is still wrong. See: http://ideone.com/zHrAHQ

Comment: I works in Javascript. Updated for PHP. And to answer your question: I didn't try the first regex no. Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: This won't scale too well, will negatively impact performance, and will be hassle to maintain, as you'd have to add a new lookahead for each capture group. But I have to give you a +1 for creativity and proving the concept works ;)

Comment: Well, yeah, but then again regexes are so cool I couldn't resist :) Thanks for the thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. Regex isn't designed to sort. You could setup two different regular expressions to check for each pattern though. This code will echo the two string in num/alpha order as you requested:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$string1 = 'aaa-123';
$string2 = '123-aaa';

echo 'String 1: '.$string1."\n";
echo 'String 2: '.$string2."\n";

$pattern1 = '/([\d]+)-([a-z]+)/i';
$pattern2 = '/([a-z]+)-([\d]+)/i';

echo 'Result 1: ';
if(preg_match($pattern1, $string1, $matches))
{
    echo $matches[1].' '.$matches[2]."\n";
}
if(preg_match($pattern2, $string1, $matches))
{
    echo $matches[2].' '.$matches[1]."\n";
}

echo 'Result 2: ';
if(preg_match($pattern1, $string2, $matches))
{
    echo $matches[1].' '.$matches[2]."\n";
}
if(preg_match($pattern2, $string2, $matches))
{
    echo $matches[2].' '.$matches[1]."\n";
}
?>
```

The resulting output is:

```
String 1: aaa-123
String 2: 123-aaa
Result 1: 123 aaa
Result 2: 123 aaa
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the digits to be there first, you need to sort the array yourself.

`array_sort()` will... sort it out for you.

Comment: @downvoter: How is this answer not helpful? (Aside from the little joke which was removed within 20 seconds (well done @KingCrunch).

Comment: You have to admit the joke wasn't funny.

Comment: @NullUserException: It wasn't, I'm very tired.